# VPN Client can access local subnet but not gateway

Tags: windows, vpn

We have a 2012 VPN server which is allowing the VPN clients to access servers on the same subnet, but does not allow routing to the default gateway.

The server is configured in RRAS as an IPv4 Router for the "Local area network (LAN) routing only", RADIUS authentication, IPv4 Forwarding is enabled and the server can assign IPv4 DHCP addresses.  We are not running IPv6.

The server has an IP of x.x.96.58 and a gateway of x.x.96.1.  The VPN clients get IPs in the 96.185 - 220 range and are able to access servers and computers in the 96.0 subnet, but can not ping 96.1.

We HAVE been able to ping 96.254 (which goes to our firewall) that contains the routing table for our other networks, but when we try to put the static route in, the ping still does not succeed to the remote networks.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall RRAS, this time use 'Custom' and only select VPN Server.

Also include the results of `route print` on the client machine, the client needs to know how to get to the remote subnet, not the server.  You can play with manually adding routes on the client machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, we have a backup VPN server which worked 2 months ago and the settings are exactly the same (or appear to be on the surface).  Other than checking Windows Adv Firewall settings, are there any other settings which would be blocking the routing?